# GetVirtualPath not being called on custom Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a custom route called `CustomRoute` which performs various things on the `GetVirtualPath` method (for this example I'm setting the entire URL to lowercase) with the following structure:

```
public sealed class CustomRoute : Route
{
    public CustomRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, routeHandler) { }
    public CustomRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, routeHandler) { }
    public CustomRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler) { }
    public CustomRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler) { }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

        if (path != null)
        {
            path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath.ToLowerInvariant();
        }

        return path;
    }
}
```

I'm adding this route to my route collection through an extension method called `MapCustomRoute`:

```
public static CustomRoute MapCustomRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string url, object defaults)
{
    CustomRoute route = new CustomRoute(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler());

    routes.Add(route);

    return route;
}
```

And then finally invoking this extension on the `RouteTable.Routes` collection in global.asax:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Clear();
RouteTable.Routes.MapCustomRoute("somecontroller/someaction/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

The routing works fine and my request is mapped correctly to the corresponding controller and action - however the URL is still in uppercase. Stepping through my code, I can see that my `CustomRoute`'s constructor is being called when initializing the route - but the `GetVirtualPath` method is never called when making my request. Am I missing something obvious here, I've tried to use the route debugging tool and everything looks good so I'm at a loss here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through my questions list to close off open ones and I find this one.  This one was a strange one; to fix this I had to re-create my Visual Studio solution from scratch.  Then, by using the exact code I have above the new project worked correctly - but the old one did not.  I assume it's a weird-ism of VS 2010, I ran both solutions parallel, confirmed they had the exact same code-base and one worked, the other didn't.

Comment: What a nighmare. I cannot even _imagine_ doing this with our 89 projects. But my custom route's `GetVirtualPath()` method is also not being called :-|

Comment: Yikes @Oliver that sounds like a nightmare indeed! This wasn't too bad as it's the first, and thankfully last, time it's happened. It's super annoying that I don't know exactly what went wrong, I mean something *must have* been different between the two - things don't just stop working for no reason. I figure it was something in the .sln or .csproj files, or the compiled symbols... something!

Comment: Thanks for getting back, Paul, even after such a long time! I've finally tracked down the issue - using JetBrains Rider to (easily) debug through the ASP.NET Source code (they decompile the assemblies on demand!). It turned out to be a problem with the route registration. I had missed to set the name of the area as a DataToken on the route, thus it would not be in the filtered route collection for the area the current URL was being generated in. It was quite an odyssey! Thanks for your empathy - it helped me stay in there!

Comment: Well, that certainly sounds plausible @Oliver so I'll take it as the solution for whatever feeling of satisfaction it provides me :) thanks for perservering and getting there! It's the best any of us can hope to do.